# datepicker max date

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

So I have a date picker and I want to get back a max date. I have somthing like this

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +15D" });
```

how can I get the maxDate value formatted in MM/DD/YYYY?

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: So the main question is I have a datepicker and I want to get back the date 6 weeks from today. How do I get that date in a string?

Comment: i'm not sure there is a way to do this using the datepicker api.  the getter for maxDate will just return what you gave it,  so that's not going to help.  you might need to use a library like date.js

Comment: date.js looks awesome... if no one responds to a solution with datepicker I think you are correct =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yyyy' );
```

And then specify your `maxdate` in mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: but what if I don't know the max date? So I think I totally screwed up the questio here. I have a datepicker, and i want it to get me a string of the date 6 weeks from today...

Comment: somethin glike this $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+6w" }); and all I need is the maxDate value

Comment: one more last thing though... I copied and pasted your code and I get an alert as +1M +15D not the date value... yet I can see your code working perfectly in jsfiddle... any clues?

Comment: great thinking!  i never would have thought of using the dateFormat option this way!

Comment: @climboid: You might try initializing all of the datepicker options at once instead of separately as I did in the jsFiddle. Aside from that, make sure you're wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){`. If that doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: @wanovak thank you so much for helping out even when the question is marked as answered. Here is what I have $(document).ready(function(){  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +15D",dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy' });  var maxDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate");alert(maxDate); }); and I still get as an alert +1m +15D

Comment: I just tried that code, and you're right it didn't work. And for some reason, when I split up the dateFormat option like before, it worked. So it's not working when the code is identical to the jsFiddle I posted earlier? (Except the document.ready, put that in and don't combine the dateFormat option.)

Comment: Yeah man this to gives me the same alert    $(document).ready(function(){$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +15D" });$('#datepicker').datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'mm/dd/yy' );var maxDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate");alert(maxDate);  });                     very freaky....

Comment: Since it works in jsFiddle, my only thought is that you're running either a different version of jQuery or a different version of jQueryUI. Make sure that your versions match those specified in jsFiddle. If they're the same, then you might consider re-opening this question.

Comment: I do have different versions of jquery... that might be it then... any way thanks a lot man

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this is what I used: `{ maxDate: '+2m +2w +4y' }`

Comment: ok but how do I extrapolate that from the object into a string? if I do a console.log of var endDate = $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" }); I get an object

Comment: Oh, I see what you were meaning, my bad. Wanovak has the answer it appears

Comment: hmmm so what I have is this $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+6w" }); and I only need the maxDate value in a string... since I don't know what the end date could be I'm using datepicker to figure it out...